# Add HTML code in a target place through WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I want to write a piece of text through a WordPress plugin in HTML theme between post and comments section.

I want to know is there any way that I can do this no matter what theme is installed and I can show my message between comments section and posts content.

Let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: If anybody has tried to dig in, "How does Disqus Plugin" add its HTML code below posts?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where you want to display your message in comment section? After post comment button or in the starting of the comment section?

Comment: Starting of the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever theme you are using there must be a file in the name comments.php to display commenting section. To find this file open **\wp-content\themes\YOUR_THEME\comments.php**. Here you can your message wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, I know but I want to modify this file via plugin. I want to add my dynamic message in it through a plugin.

Comment: To bind dynamic section in comment section refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template. Disqus is using the following code `add_filter('comments_template', 'dsq_comments_template');` in **\wp-content\plugins\disqus-comment-system\disqus.php** which will load the commenting section from comment.php

Comment: If you want display your message at the starting of the comment section, then you can use javascript. You can prepend your message inside the id **#comments**

Comment: Hi, overwriting the template solved the problem, #comment might not be the comment section ID in all themes so thats why I am afraid that it won't work.